# Wordpress: Using WP_Query to get attachment returns empty set

Tags: php, attachment, wordpress

I would like to get the first audio file in the media library filtered by a custom field, but it always returns an empty set of posts. I know that I have to pass `'post_status' => 'inherit'` and `'post_type' => 'attachment'`, but it doesn't change anything.

```
<?php
    // Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'audio', 
        'meta_key' => 'my_meta_key', 
        'meta_value' => 'my_meta_value', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1 );

    // Create the query
    $audio_files = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Output
    var_dump( $audio_files );    // the number of found posts is always 0

?>
```

So I tried to minimise it by letting away all the meta-key-stuff and searched for any attachment (as mentioned [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters))

```
<?php
    // Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_status' => 'inherit' );   // or "any", but without effect

    // Create the query
    $any_files = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Output
    var_dump( $any_files );    // same: the number of found posts is always 0
?>
```

So I tried it the old-fashioned way by a custom SQL-statement:

```
<?php
    // Get row by custom SQL-statement
    $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts p, ' . $wpdb->prefix .  'postmeta m WHERE p.post_mime_type LIKE "audio/%" AND p.ID = m.post_ID AND m.meta_key = "my_meta_key" AND m.meta_value = "my_meta_value" ORDER BY p.post_date DESC' );
?>
```

And tataaaa! I get my first audio file.

I know there are similar questions:

- [Broken? WP_Query and “attachment” as a post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/broken-wp-query-and-attachment-as-a-post-type)
- [WP_Query not working as expected for attachments and custom meta_query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52194/wp-query-not-working-as-expected-for-attachments-and-custom-meta-query)

But neither of them helped me, even though they were treating quite the same topic.

What I am missing here? I would like to use `WP_Query`.

Comment: You may get better help asking this @ [The Official WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: used your code. works fine for me. Didnt find any issue with it. May be you are not having any related data for the query u fired.

Comment: Yes, I have. My custom query returns the expected result. Triple checked that before asking here :D

Answer (score 0):

you should use offset,orderby and order when you are using posts_per_page it should definitely work. here is your revised code

if posts_per_page is -1 then it will list all post so in that case offset is ignored but in all other case you should use.

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
         'offset'         => $offset,
        'post_mime_type' => 'audio', 
        'meta_key' => 'my_meta_key', 
         'orderby' =>'ID',
        'order'  => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => 'my_meta_value', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1 );
```